# How can I find all the words in a file that contain every vowel?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

In `myfile.txt`, I want to get a list of words that contain at least one occurrence of every vowel [`aeoui`] (case insensitive). I preferably want to do this with `grep`.

My guess is to start off with the following command, to get a list of the words, but I wouldn't know what pipes to put after it, to get the wanted result.

```
grep -Eo "\w+"
```

Comment: `sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+/\n/g' myfile.txt | grep a | grep e | grep i | grep o | grep u`? Or `sed -E s/[[:space:]]+/\n/g' myfile.txt | awk '/a/ && /e/ && /i/ && /o/ && /u/'` for a non-grep approach.

Comment: See: [grep to find words with all vowels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156134/74329)

Comment: The regex in the dupe above works with `grep -iP` ...

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- OP has determined that `grep -Eo "\w+"` returns an accurate list of `'words'`

Some sample data:

```
$ cat vowels.dat
this is a test.
and, this, in another test
what about hyphen-ated-words?
some nonsense to match XaXeXiXoXuX
more non-sense xAxExIxOxUx
```

OP's `grep` applied to this data:

```
$ grep -Eo "\w+" vowels.dat
this
is
a
test
and
this
in
another
test
what
about
hyphen
ated
words
some
nonsense
to
match
XaXeXiXoXuX          # contains all 5x vowels
more
non
sense
xAxExIxOxUx          # contains all 5x vowels
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk '
BEGIN { split("aeiou",vowels,"") }                # populate an array of lowercase vowels
      { cnt=0                                     # reset our match counter
        lcword=tolower($0)                        # convert our word to lower case (takes care on case-insensitive requirement)
        for ( i in vowels )                       # loop through array of vowels
            if ( lcword ~ vowels[i] )             # if our lowercase input contains the current loop/vowel ...
               cnt++                              # increment our match counter
        if ( cnt == 5 )                           # if we have 5 matches ...
           print $0                               # print the current word to stdout
      }
' <(grep -Eo "\w+" vowels.dat)
```

This generates:

```
XaXeXiXoXuX
xAxExIxOxUx
```

Answer (score 0):

***1st solution:*** Considering that OP wants to print words which are having all vowels then try following.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if((sub(/[Aa]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Ee]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Ii]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Oo]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Uu]/,"&",$i))==5){
      print $i
    }
  }
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){      ##Looping through all fields here.
    if((sub(/[Aa]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Ee]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Ii]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Oo]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Uu]/,"&",$i))==5){      ##Checking condition if substituting aA|eE|iI|oO|uU has cout 5 in current field(means all are found) then do following.
      print $i             ##printing current field here.
    }
  }
}'  Input_file             ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to print count of words which have all vowels in it present then try following.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if((sub(/[Aa]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Ee]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Ii]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Oo]/,"&",$i)+sub(/[Uu]/,"&",$i))==5){
      count++
    }
  }
}
END{
  print "Total="count
}
'  Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** Both the solution will take care of ignore-case option while looking for vowels in words.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
         if($i~/[aA]/ && $i~/[eE]/ && $i~/[iI]/ && $i~/[oO]/ && $i~/[uU]/) 
              print $I}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it only with grep, try a series of greps for each required letter:

```sh
grep -Eo "\w+" myfile.txt | grep -i a | grep -i e | grep -i i | grep -i o | grep -i u
```

Answer (score 0):

another `awk` with multichar RS support.

```
$ awk -v RS=' +|\n|\t' '(w=tolower($0)) ~ /a/ && w ~ /e/ && w ~ /i/ && w ~ /o/ && w ~ /u/' file
```